# How to create turn based game loop in SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2, game-development

I am coding in C and I have been struggling with this for a while. I understand the basic concept of a game loop. My game at the top level looks like this in pseudo code:

```
while (does_not_quit){
        input();
        logic();
        render()
        }
```

where:

```
input(){ 
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                exit(0);
                break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                do_stuff(key);
                break;

            case SDL_KEYUP:
                do_stuff(key);
                break;
            }
        }
```

This works fine in the main game but I want to achieve a system where at the press of a button the user can go into a turn based mode of combat, whereby
the npcs and player turn order is determined by their attributes.

My naive approach right now is to initiate this mode at the press of a key (say "C"), then sort all the visible entities and player according to their
combat initiative into a linked list. Then I loop through the linked list, with each entity moving in turn, the problem is how do I stop the loop when it is
the player's turn and await user input to determine the moves? Right now the loop of course just runs over and over again per step of the logic() and there
is no time for the user to react.

I thought about adding an additional while(SDL_PollEvent(&turnEvent)) inside logic() after the user initiates the turn based combat mode but I can't quite
make sense of the idea.

Is anyone familiar with this sort of setup? It's a common troupe in role player games, where exploration occurs in real time but as a enemy is encountered the game switches to turn-based.

Comment: This question is almost certainly better suited for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (as per the [`game-development`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/game-development/info) tag) as there is not a specific programming question here, but more of a vague game design one.

Comment: You do not want to block your loop in order to create a turn-based game. You may want some items that render in real-time even though the game itself is turn-based. For instance, animations for the friendly and enemy sprites. **For turn-based games, you want to implement a state machine that is fully decoupled from the main loop.** Certain actions, like clicking a button or pressing a key, initiate a transition in the state machine. Most of your game logic will be implemented in these state transitions through side effects. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: Hi Michael, could you give me a rough idea of what that would look like? Should I run two separate while loops on different threads? One that controls the main game and a separate one that controls when the game enters turn based mode? I will try the gamedev.stackexchange as suggested as well. thank you

Comment: Do not use `exit(0)`, call a clean up function and clean all your resources first.